# GWT Disclosure panel bug

Tags: google-chrome, gwt

I have a GWT Disclosure panel which is animating between open and closed state in an endless loop, when the disclosure button is clicked. But this seems to only be happening in the Chrome browser, not Safari or Firefox. Anyone know what this is about?

```
DisclosurePanel disclosurePanel = new DisclosurePanel("Reset password");
    disclosurePanel.setAnimationEnabled(true);
    disclosurePanel.setContent(passwordGrid);
    disclosurePanel.addOpenHandler(new OpenHandler<DisclosurePanel>() {

        public void onOpen(OpenEvent<DisclosurePanel> event) {
            saveButton.setEnabled(false);//enable on close or after verifying current password

        }
    });
    disclosurePanel.addCloseHandler(new CloseHandler<DisclosurePanel>() {

        public void onClose(CloseEvent<DisclosurePanel> event) {
            saveButton.setEnabled(true);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a issue reported for latest chrome browser - http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=158910

Related information - https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?spec=svn10989&r=10989

Other Stackoverflow answer - [GWT DeckLayoutPanel animation goes into infinite loop on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317709/gwt-decklayoutpanel-animation-goes-into-infinite-loop-on-chrome)

Comment: Thank you! It was a bug in GWT. Upgrading to GWT 2.5 fixed the issue.